# Issue with fetching and processing Apple stock prices from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve and analyze Apple stock prices from a CSV file. I have provided a sample output here for reference.

However, I'm facing an issue where my code is not displaying the requested columns from the CSV file, and I'm not receiving any error messages. I suspect there might be a problem with my definitions or something else that I'm missing.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
f_list = list()
file_object = ()
my_tot = dict()
new_list = list()

def get_input_descriptor():
    while True:
        filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
        if filename == 'table.csv':
            with open(filename, "r") as infile:
                infile.readlines()[1:]
                # for line in lines:
                #     print(line.rstrip())
                break
        else:
            print("Bad file name, try again")
    return filename

def get_data_list(file_object, column_number):
    dict = {}
    for val in file_object:
        date = val.split(",")[0]
        data = float(val.split(",")[column_number])
        dict[date] = data
    return dict.items()

def average_data(new_list):
    for date, price in new_list:
        my_tot[date] = my_tot.get(date, 0) + float(price)
        my_times[date] = my_times.get(date, 0) + 1
    for key in my_tot:
        f_list.append((float(my_tot[key] / my_times[key]), key))


def main():
    get_input_descriptor()
    column_number = int(input("Which column: "))
    date_list = get_data_list(file_object, column_number)
    final_list = average_data(date_list)
    x = sorted(f_list)
    print('Lowest 6:')
    for tup in x[:6]:
        print
        tup[0], tup[1]
    print('Highest 6:')
    x = sorted(f_list, reverse=True)
    for tup in x[:6]:
        print
        tup[0], tup[1]

    while 1:
        flag = input("do you want to continue? ")
        if flag == '' or not flag[0].lower() in ['y', 'n']:
            print("Please answer with a yes or no")
        else:
            break
    if flag[0].lower() == 'y':
        column = input("Which column: ")
        print(column)

    if flag[0].lower() == 'n':
        print("Bye!")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example output:

```
Enter a file name: name.csv
Which column 2: 
Lowest 2 for column 2
Date: mm/dd/yyyy, Value: x.xx
Date: mm/dd/yyyy, Value: x.xx
```

Comment: Please post your code as text. Read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: What is the actual question you are asking :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include code in your question, not just linked. Also... you've presented what you're trying to do, but what is your *question*? What is wrong, or how do your results differ from what you want?

Comment: @apr_1985 Better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look around your `get_input_descriptor` method.

1. What are you returning from the method?
2. Where is the returned information being stored in the main method (is it being stored at all?)
3. What are you doing with the lines that you read from the file?
4. What is the `file_object` you are passing into `get_data_list`

My main advice would be to add `print` everywhere for debugging.  See what it stored in your variables at different points in the program and see where a variable doesn't contain what you think it should

Comment: @BurntChickenNugget did you take a look at this answer? If not, it's excellent advice. If so, and it gave you the pointers you needed, please consider clicking the checkmark next to it to accept the answer.